# Custom output filename from piped batch file

Tags: batch-file

when using > to pipe command output to a file, is there a way for the output filename to be dynamic?

simple example

c:\systeminformation > \servername\share\sysinfo.txt (output filename is sysinfo.txt, and can be overwrote, or appended by using >>)

Is there a command I can add that will give a unique output filename? if nothing else, maybe a DTS stamp.txt format? that way the output filename is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can attach the date and time to a file name dynamically if that serves your purpose.

Example:

```
set dynamicFname=sysinfo_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%date:~10%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%.txt
c:\systeminformation > \servername\share\%dynamicFname%
```

the resulted file name will be something like this:

sysinfo_04_11_2014_16_44.txt
sysinfo_04_11_2014_16_47.txt

04=month, 11=day, 2014=year, 16=hours in 24 format, 44=minutes

note that you need to run the set command every time you want to update the date/time stored in the varible "dynamicFname"

the solution is inspired by this url:
http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-130043-dos-create-filename-based-on-date

Comment: thanks to all who replied to my question, the response from 'DoubleM' was spot on. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fundamentally all you need is to put the filename into a variable.

```
set "var=\servername\share\sysinfo.txt"
whatevercommand >"%var%"
```

Beyond that, your question is too vague. There are special circumstances where this technique needs to be varied (but I'd guess you'd need `\\servername\...`)

Answer (score 0):

```
c:\systeminformation > \\servername\share\sysinfo%random%.txt
```

or

```
set name=%date:/=_%
c:\systeminformation > \\servername\share\sysinfo%name%.txt
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Type set /? for the documentation on both commands (even though first one doesn't use set it is still documented there). First is a random number. Second is the date with slashes, illegal in filenames, replaced with underscore.